# How to stop vertical slick from scrolling in two divs when hovering just one?

Tags: html, slick.js

I have a vertical slick working on two inline divs. The issue is that when I hover on the left div, it stops scrolling but the right one continues, and after that, the slider looses it's sycronization. Is there a way to stop them both when hovering just one? (left or right?) The HTML:

```
<div class="vertical-scroll">
            <!--SCROLL TITLES-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-5">
                    <h2 class="">
                        <?php echo $right; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2 class="">
                        <?php echo $left; ?>
                    </h2>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-5">
                    <h2 class="info-title">
                        <?php echo $right2; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2 class="">
                        <?php echo $left2; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
 jQuery('.vertical-scroll').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: false,
    touchMove: false,
    swipe: false,
     pauseOnHover: true,
    arrows: false,
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what the end result you are going for is, but you can use 'asNavFor' to make one slick slider stay in sync with another.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3adk0uz/12/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="slider-1 text-center">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-2 text-center">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.slider-1').slick({
      vertical:true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 500,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      asNavFor: '.slider-2'
    });
    $('.slider-2').slick({
      vertical:true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-1'
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @john, but they are already syncronized when moving, but when I hover, just one stops

Comment: When you hover on the top one, both stop, in my example. 

Edit: I had forgetten to update, the fiddle now links to the right version and does what I say above. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3adk0uz/12/)

Comment: it was my markup wrongly set, but thanks anyway for the answer @john

Comment: Great to hear you figured it out. With slick I find that it's best to start with a simple case and then just add to it slowly, so start with some basic html and then build on that. Good Luck @Mellville